# LC3 specific character

Tags: lc3

How to check if the user entered the valid character in LC3 "Assembly Language"? For example, I want the entered characters between 0 through 9, or letters from A through F? Like if the user entered any other characters it will not be printed in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com

Once you get an input character from the console, check its value to see if it is in the range you're looking for.  In other words, if you're checking for '0'-'9', you can check for a value between 0x30 and 0x39.